# User does not have permission to access this object . with storage firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am making an android application which is sort of a social media app 
but when I am trying to put image from gallery or from camera for profile or cover this problem occurs.

I want the user to select a photo from his gallery or take a new picture using camera and then upload the image to Firebase Storage.

User does not have permission to access this object using Firebase Storage.

There are my permissions ..

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

My Java Code:

```
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
FirebaseUser user;
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;


StorageReference storageReference;

String storagePath = "Uers_Profile_Cover_Imgs/";

ImageView avatartv, coverTv;
TextView nameTv, emailTv, phoneTv;
FloatingActionButton fab;

ProgressDialog pd;

private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
private static final int STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
private static final int IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_CODE = 300;
private static final int IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE = 400;

String cameraPermissions[];
String storagePermission[];

Uri image_uri;

String profileOrCoverPhoto;

public ProfileFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Users");
    storageReference = getInstance().getReference();

    cameraPermissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
    storagePermission = new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};


    avatartv = view.findViewById(R.id.avatarTv);
    coverTv = view.findViewById(R.id.coverTv);
    nameTv = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    emailTv = view.findViewById(R.id.category);
    phoneTv = view.findViewById(R.id.location);
    fab = view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

    Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("email").equalTo(user.getEmail());
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String name = "" + ds.child("name").getValue();
                String image = "" + ds.child("image").getValue();
                String email = "" + ds.child("email").getValue();
                String phone = "" + ds.child("phone").getValue();
                String cover = "" + ds.child("cover").getValue();

                nameTv.setText(name);
                emailTv.setText(email);
                phoneTv.setText(phone);

                try {
                    Picasso.get().load(image).into(avatartv);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.ic_add_a_photo_black_24dp).into(avatartv);

                }
                try {
                    Picasso.get().load(cover).into(coverTv);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showEditProfileDialog();
        }
    });

    return view;
}

private boolean checkStoragePermission() {
    boolean result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            == (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    return result;
}

private void requestStoragePermission() {
    requestPermissions(storagePermission, STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
}

private boolean checkCameraPermission() {
    boolean result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            == (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);


    boolean result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            == (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    return result && result1;
}

private void requestCameraPermission() {
    requestPermissions(cameraPermissions, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
}

private void showEditProfileDialog() {
    String options[] = {"Edit Profile Picture", "Edit Cover Photo", "Edit Name", "Edit Phone"};

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Choose Action");
    builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (which == 0) {
                pd.setMessage("Updating Profile Picture");
                profileOrCoverPhoto = "image";
                showImagePicDialog();
            } else if (which == 1) {
                pd.setMessage("Updating Cover Picture");
                profileOrCoverPhoto = "cover";
                showImagePicDialog();

            } else if (which == 2) {
                pd.setMessage("Updating Name");
                showNamePhoneUpdateDialog("name");
            } else if (which == 3) {
                pd.setMessage("Updating Phone");
                showNamePhoneUpdateDialog("phone");

            }
        }
    });
    builder.create().show();
}

private void showNamePhoneUpdateDialog(String Key) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Updated " + Key);

    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    linearLayout.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);

    EditText editText = new EditText(getActivity());
    editText.setHint("Enter " + Key);
    linearLayout.addView(editText);

    builder.setView(linearLayout);

    builder.setPositiveButton("Update", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String value = editText.getText().toString().trim();
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(value)) {
                pd.show();
                HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
                result.put(Key, value);
                databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).updateChildren(result)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                pd.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Updated...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        pd.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter " + Key, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });
    builder.create().show();
}

private void showImagePicDialog() {
    String options[] = {"Camera", "Gallery"};

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Pick Image From");
    builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (which == 0) {
                if (!checkCameraPermission()) {
                    requestCameraPermission();
                } else {
                    pickFromCamera();
                }
            } else if (which == 1) {
                if (!checkStoragePermission()) {
                    requestStoragePermission();
                } else {
                    pickFromGallery();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    builder.create().show();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                boolean cameraAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                boolean writeStorageAccepted = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                if (cameraAccepted && writeStorageAccepted) {
                    pickFromCamera();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please Enable Camera & Storage Permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
        break;
        case STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                boolean writeStorageAccepted = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                if (writeStorageAccepted) {
                    pickFromGallery();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please Enable Storage Permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }break;
            }
        }
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_CODE) {
            image_uri = data.getData();

            uploadProfileCoverPhoto(image_uri);
        }
        if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE) {

            uploadProfileCoverPhoto(image_uri);

        }

    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

private void uploadProfileCoverPhoto(Uri uri) {
    String filePathAndName = storagePath + "" + profileOrCoverPhoto + "_" + user.getUid();
    StorageReference storageReference2nd = storageReference.child(filePathAndName);
    storageReference2nd.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            Task<Uri> uriTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
            while (!uriTask.isSuccessful()) ;
            Uri downloadUri = uriTask.getResult();

            if (uriTask.isSuccessful()) {
                HashMap<String, Object> results = new HashMap<>();
                results.put(profileOrCoverPhoto, downloadUri.toString());
                databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).updateChildren(results)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                pd.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Image Updated ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        pd.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error Updating Image ...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
            } else {
                pd.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Some error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            pd.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

private void pickFromCamera() {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "Temp Pic");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Temp Description");

    image_uri = getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, image_uri);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE);

}

private void pickFromGallery() {
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_CODE);
}
```

XML Codes:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ProfileFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/coverTv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:background="#FFA117">


            </ImageView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/avatarTv"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/face" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#B67310"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="25sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/category"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="15dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/location"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="15dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/editpen"
        app:backgroundTint="#FFA117" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

FIrebase Security Rules:

```
   service firebase.storage {
     match /b/learno-fc8fc.appspot.com/o {
      // Allow access by all users
      allow read, write;
    }
```

[image]
Screenshot of the issue.

Comment: Yes, 
the problem was in my rules you should make it like that ..

            `service firebase.storage { match /b/learno-fc8fc.appspot.com/o { match /{allPaths=**} { // Allow access by all users allow read, write; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please cross check your bucket name if it correct.

Answer (score 0):

After searching i found solution .. 
My rules in Firebase was not right ..

we should make it like that ..

```
    service firebase.storage
 { match /b/learno-fc8fc.appspot.com/o 
{ match /{allPaths=**}
 { // Allow access by all users 
allow read, write; }
```